# Is there anything wrong with my method for calling NHibernate in async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement Identity's `IUserStore<TUser, in TKey>` with NHibernate, which lacks the async methods required by `IUserStore`. This is my ignorant attempt at dispatching the blocking call and making the method async:

```
public class QsaasUserStore<TLogin> : IUserStore<QsaasUser<TLogin>, int> where TLogin : QsaasUserLogin<int>
{
    public Task CreateAsync(QsaasUser<TLogin> user)
    {
        var session = NHibertnateSessionProvidser.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => session.Save(user))
            .ContinueWith(ex => Trace.TraceError(ex?.Exception?.Message ?? "Strange task fault"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
}
```

I have gleaned the above from some initial Googling, and it seems OK to me, but I think I could do better with exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NHibernate session is not thread-safe.

You are retrieving a session on one thread, and then calling `Save` on a different thread. This might work, and might even work most of the time, but you are in 'undefined behavior' territory.

The interface you are implementing requires you to return a task. You can fulfill this constraint without involving background threads.

```
public class QsaasUserStore<TLogin> : IUserStore<QsaasUser<TLogin>, int> where TLogin : QsaasUserLogin<int>
{
    public Task CreateAsync(QsaasUser<TLogin> user)
    {
        var session = NHibertnateSessionProvidser.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        session.Save(user);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

If you really want to run it on a worker thread, then use the background thread to both retrieve the session and call `Save`. This will only work if your `SessionFactory` is smart enough to map different sessions to different threads.

```
public Task CreateAsync(QsaasUser<TLogin> user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
               var session = NHibertnateSessionProvidser.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
                session.Save(user);
        }).ContinueWith(ex => Trace.TraceError(ex?.Exception?.Message ?? "Strange task fault"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
```

Comment: I think I like your second suggestion. The session is opened and closed per request, so I don't think that's an issue.